# Limiting execution time and attempts with asynchronous retry decorator for database connectivity

Tags: python, asynchronous, decorator

```
import asyncio
import random
import time
from typing import Callable, Awaitable

class TooManyRetries(Exception):
    pass

# Decorator code

def retry_on_timeout(max_retries: int, timeout: float, retry_interval: float):
    
    def decorator(coro: Callable[[], Awaitable]):
        
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
           
            for retry_num in range(0, max_retries + 1):
                try:
                    # Start timing
                    start_time = time.time()
                    result = await asyncio.wait_for(coro(*args, **kwargs), timeout=timeout)
                    # Calculate execution time
                    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

                    if elapsed_time <= timeout:
                        return result

                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    # Timeout handling, retry if the maximum number of retries is not reached
                    if retry_num < max_retries:
                        print(f"Function '{coro.__name__}' exceeded the timeout of {timeout} seconds. Retrying... (Retry {retry_num + 1})")
                        await asyncio.sleep(retry_interval)

                except Exception as e:
                    # Other exception handling, exit the retry loop directly
                    print(f"Function '{coro.__name__}' raised an exception: {e}")
                    break

            # Function reached the maximum number of retries, raise an exception
            raise TooManyRetries(f"Function '{coro.__name__}' exceeded the maximum number of retries ({max_retries}).")

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

I wrote this decorator with the hope of limiting the execution time and the number of attempts.
I used it to restrict connections to the database.
Although it still works fine with simple queries, it fails with time-consuming queries and shows the error message

> TypeError: object DataFrame can't be used in 'await' expression

[image]

Here is my code with connecting to the database.

```
class MySQLQuery:
    
        # Read the configuration file and get database connection information
        with open("config.json", 'r') as file:
            config = json.load(file)

        self.mysql_db = config['mysql']
        
        # Create and configure a logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # Create a file handler and set the formatter
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler("mysql_query.log")
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        # Add the file handler to the logger
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    def print_db_name(self):
        print(list(self.mysql_db.keys()))

    def get_db_info(self, database: str) -> dict:
        
        # Retrieve the database connection information based on the provided database name
        database_info_result = self.mysql_db.get(database)
        return database_info_result
 
    def get_dataframe(self, database: str, queries: Union[str, List[str]]) -> Union[pd.DataFrame, dict]:

        if isinstance(queries, str):
            # If a single query is provided, execute it and return the DataFrame
            return self._execute_query(database, queries)
        elif isinstance(queries, list):
            # If a list of queries is provided, execute them and return the dictionary of DataFrames
            results = {}
            for i, query in enumerate(queries):
                result_df = self._execute_query(database, query)
                results[f"result{i+1}"] = result_df
            return results
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid input for 'queries'. It should be either a single SQL query (str) or a list of SQL queries (List[str]).")

    def _execute_query(self, database: str, query: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
        
        # The internal method to execute a single SQL query and return the result as a DataFrame
        info = self.get_db_info(database)
        host = info['host']
        user = info['user']
        password = info['pass']
        port = info['port']

        try:
            # Open a database connection
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, port=port)

            # Create a cursor to execute the query
            cursor = cnx.cursor()

            # Execute the SQL query and fetch the result
            cursor.execute(query)
            result = cursor.fetchall()

            # Get column names
            column_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]

            # Convert the result to a DataFrame
            result_df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=column_names)

        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f"Connection failed: {e}")
            result_df = pd.DataFrame()  # Return an empty DataFrame if an error occurs

        finally:
            # Close the database connection
            cursor.close()
            cnx.close()
            self.logger.info("Connection ended")

        return result_df
```

I want to know how to write the code successfully, which provides the exact data and respects the limitations imposed by the decorator.
Additionally, I'm interested in learning how to apply this decorator to any code that may require a significant amount of time.

Comment: You are using `await mysql_query.get_dataframe(...)`, but `get_dataframe` is defined as a normal method with `def`. To use it with `await`, it needs to be defined with `async def`.

Comment: `@retry_on_timeout(max_retries=3, timeout=10, retry_interval=2)
async def main():
    mysql_query = MySQLQuery()
    database_name = 'data'
    query = """select *
                from """
    tarl = await mysql_query.get_dataframe(database_name, query)
    print(tarl)

asyncio.run(main())`

But it didn't finish in 34 seconds.

Comment: I don't know what your last comment means. All I can say is that `await mysql_query.get_dataframe(database_name, query)` is wrong, given how `get_dataframe` is defined. Either remove the `await`, or change `def get_dataframe` to `async def get_dataframe`.